# Can't find exe after compilation succeeds

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am unable to find an executable file after successfully debugging the code of face detection in microsoft visual studio 2008 using opencv. There is no error only three warnings but it shows the build has succeeded.

Comment: i'm assuming you've checked `bin/debug` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go into project settings and check for the output folder, look for your binaries there.

Binaries don't necesseraly mean `exe` files, they can also be `dll`'s or `lib`'s. Are you sure your program generates an exe?

EDIT: As per your comment... it asks for an exe file? Are you just compiling, or hitting F5, because F5 will go in debug mode. If no exe is generated, you'll be prompted to pick an exe to run, as dll's cant be ran.

Comment: It is not making any executable file at all. I have searched for it but i could not find it anywhere. after the program is debugged completely, following is displayed:     1>Linking...
1>avi1.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001F) for 'CvCapture'; image may not run
1>Embedding manifest...
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Abdullah\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\avi1\avi1\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>avi1 - 0 error(s), 3 warning(s)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
afier that it asks for exe file

Comment: yes some dll files are built. but how will i get an executable file?

Comment: @Abdullahx what do you mean some dll's are built? Are there more projects? If it's just one, only one binary will be built. With third-party modules, you can't really change what they generate (dll or exe). If you have your own module, just create a new project and choose a configuration that outputs an exe (like a win32 application).

Comment: Yes that helped. thanks a lot. I was not selecting the option "win 32 application".

Answer (score 2):

In the project property pages: Configuration Properties -> General -> Output Directory. That value tells you where the compiler leaves its output.

Comment: i have checked that folder and found nothing.