# Visual Studio cannot find my C++ hello world file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this code, this message keeps popping up even though I copied and pasted straight from online. There are no build errors either. 
[Here's the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQZDa.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio complains that .exe is not found when compiling for debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620939/visual-studio-complains-that-exe-is-not-found-when-compiling-for-debug)

Comment: What is it, Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? Chris assumed it's the former, and changed the tag to 'visual-studio'. If you're using VSC, change the tag back and fix the title. And you forgot the error message.

Comment: Seems not be about compiling but finding the exe as Luka said?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I based it on the message box with the error having the title "Microsoft Visual Studio".

Comment: Related to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148418/cant-find-exe-after-compilation-succeeds

Comment: There should be a build error. `endl` is in the standard namespace, but you aren't using that. Try: `std::endl` the same way you do with `cout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the file from the new file option not directly from the source file once I created the c++ project.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code. Could be your antivirus deleting the exe before visual studio can start it. Try disabling your antivirus and run from VS again.

If not antivirus, then something else is deleting it.

Check if the exe shown in the path in your image is really there or not.

Comment: That would be a very trigger happy antivirus.

Comment: Ive had an antivirus mark my compiled exes, dont remember what i did to fix it tho..

Comment: That has happened to me too but it was because I had some bugs causing bad memory access.

Comment: No the antivirus didn't show deleting anything in its history. The .cpp file is in the correct file but there isn't a .exe file though the directory has the path leading to the cpp file right.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231463/visual-studio-compiles-but-the-exe-isnt-there

Answer (score 0):

If you click Build -> Build Solution, you will get an error:

> error C2065: 'endl': undeclared identifier.

I suggest you should try to use `std::endl`

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And then you could try to run this code:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

that error means that the .exe file is most likely still running. it may be that you closed it trough the "X" button, but the VS debugger is still running, so try clicking on the red square to stop it or go in your task manager and manually kill the process.

it may also be that the exe is opened by another process such as a hex editor which is denying further execution access to the file, but i have had this issue personally before and the fix above worked.